# How to get last inserted id in Postgresql with OpenERP

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I have a insert query and I want to get last inserted id in OpenERP. Here is the code:

```
query = "INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM bar"
cr.execute(query) # cr => cursor
```

How to get last inserted id(s)? What happened when insertion is empty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [RETURNING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-insert.html).

```
INSERT INTO table [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
    { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...] | query }
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ AS output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

> Insert a single row into table distributors, returning the sequence number generated by the DEFAULT clause:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets')
   RETURNING did;
```

Answer (score 1):

`RETURNING` works great if you're running v8.2+. Otherwise you'll probably be looking at using `currval()` ([doc here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the link to openerp tag, I'd have to advise you to use the openerp orm. For the orm calling the create method will return the id of the newly created record. (It also then works for any osv_memory classes you may have defined)

**Reference:** http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html#osv.osv.osv.create

**Example:**

```
new_id = self.pool.get('model.name').create(cr, uid, {'name': 'New Name'})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Sentinel's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853948/how-to-get-last-inserted-id-in-postgresql-with-openerp/5853998#5853998) of the [PostgreSQL RETURNING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-insert.html) is the easiest thing for you to use.

You might also be interested in how OpenERP's ORM class manages id values for new records. Here's a snippet from the [`orm.create()`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/3399/openerp/osv/orm.py#L3578) method:

```
    # Try-except added to filter the creation of those records whose filds are readonly.
    # Example : any dashboard which has all the fields readonly.(due to Views(database views))
    try:
        cr.execute("SELECT nextval('"+self._sequence+"')")
    except:
        raise except_orm(_('UserError'),
                    _('You cannot perform this operation. New Record Creation is not allowed for this object as this object is for reporting purpose.'))
    id_new = cr.fetchone()[0]
```

It uses a sequence for each table to generate the new id value. The name of the sequence defaults to the name of the table plus '_id_seq', as you can see in the [`orm.__init__()` method](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/3399/openerp/osv/orm.py#L2850).

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but you might find it easier to use [the `orm` class](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html) to create the record for you and let it take care of the details. For example, [the create method](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html#osv.osv.osv.create) returns the id value of the new record.